# What is the use for the half bottom screen mode in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, gesture

On my iPhone, if I swipe the bottom of any app downward, the app size shrink to the bottom half of the screen as shown in the following screenshot.

What is this for? Is this a normal behavior?

[image]

Comment: "Reachability". It used to be a lot more useful when you could do it one-handed by double-tapping the home button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour is completely normal.

If I recall correctly this feature has been introduced with the iPhone 6 due to the "big" screen size. Many people can't reach the left or right upper corner when holding their phone in one hand. This feature allows you to use the upper part of your screen without switching your hand position while holding. You can disable and enable this feature in the settings.